# Make derivations over sums

Tags: derivatives, summation, logarithms

I have this kind of sums

$$ \left(\sum_{i_1=0}^{4}\sum_{i_2=0}^{4}\log(f(X,i_1,i_2))\right)'\ $$

And we want to derive in respect to $${x_i}$$, which is an element of the vector X.

How I should do that? I did basic maths at Highschool, but I do not know how to derive in respect to an element which belongs to a vector, at a function that has sums as well.

Could you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can carry the derivation into the sums, then apply the chain rule for the $\log(f(X,i_1,i_2))$ to obtain
$$\frac\partial{\partial x_i} \log(f(X,i_1, i_2)) = \frac{\frac\partial{\partial x_i}f(X,i_1,i_2)}{f(X,i_1,i_2)}$$

Comment: Ok, thanks. and what happens when I try to derivate in respect of an element of my array X?

Comment: $x_i$ already _is_ such an element, namely the $i$-th component of $X$.